# Codeigniter, registration autofill form field

Tags: php, html, sql, codeigniter

i am creating a registration page and I want to autofill the the value of certain input field whenever i choose a specific department like .when i choose the department A . it will autofill who is the supervisor on that department on my registration .how do i do it ?

this is my html view code

```
    <?php if (validation_errors()) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <center><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert" aria-hidden="true"></span><strong> Error!</strong><p><?= validation_errors(); } ?></p></center>
    </div>

    <?php if (isset($error)){ ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <center><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span><strong> Error! </strong><?= $error ?> </center>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <center> <h2>Register</h2></center>
        <hr class="colorgraph">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?= base_url().'login/registeruser' ?>" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label "><?php if(form_error('username')){ echo '<p style="color:#a94442"> * Username </p>';} else { echo 'Username'; } ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control <?php if (form_error('username')) { echo 
'alert alert-danger'.'"style="color:#000000'; } ?>" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label "><?php if(form_error('password')||form_error('confpassword')){ echo '<p style="color:#a94442"> * Password </p>';} else { echo 'Password'; } ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="password" class="form-control <?php if (form_error('password')||form_error('confpassword')) { echo 
'alert alert-danger'.'"style="color:#000000'; } ?>" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="confpassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?php if(form_error('password')||form_error('confpassword')){ echo '<p style="color:#a94442"> * Confirm Password </p>';} else { echo 'Confirm Password'; } ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="password" class="form-control <?php if (form_error('password')||form_error('confpassword')) { echo 
'alert alert-danger'.'"style="color:#000000'; } ?>" id="confpassword" name="confpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label "><?php if(form_error('email')){ 

              echo '<p style="color:#a94442"> * Email </p>';} else { echo 'Email'; } ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="email" class="form-control <?php if (form_error('email')) { echo 
'alert alert-danger'.'"style="color:#000000'; } ?>" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" 
value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?php if(form_error('fname')||form_error('mname')||form_error('lname')){ echo '<p style="color:#a94442"> * Full Name </p>';} else { echo 'Full Name'; } ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control <?php if (form_error('fname')) { echo 
'alert alert-danger'.'"style="color:#000000'; } ?>" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo set_value('fname'); ?>">
            </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
  <input type="text" value ="sa" class="form-control <?php if (form_error('mname')) { echo 
'alert alert-danger'.'"style="color:#000000'; } ?>" id="mname" name="mname" placeholder="Middle Name" value="<?php echo set_value('mname'); ?>">
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <input type="text" class="form-control <?php if (form_error('lname')) { echo 
'alert alert-danger'.'"style="color:#000000'; } ?>" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo set_value('lname'); ?>">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="gender" class="col-sm-2 control-label ">Gender</label>
            <label class="radio-inline col-sm-1 control-label">
              <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="M" selected="selected"> Male
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="F"> Female
            </label> 
           </div>

      <div class="form-group">
              <label for="gender" class="col-sm-2 control-label ">Department</label>

      <select name="Department">
      <option value="stem">STEM</option>
      <option value="gas">Saab</option>
      <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
           </select>

      </div>



          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-4 control-label">
                <h3><strong>
                        Captcha   
                          <?=$image; ?></strong></h3>
                <input type="text" id="captcha" name="captcha" height="50px" autocomplete="off" />

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <a href="<?= base_url().'login'; ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> Back</button></a>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

i want to specifically use php code .how do i do it ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use **jquery ajax** functionality for the same.